# enum in Model class throwing "NoMethodError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I searched the net and here but could not figure out why this error is coming:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `status' for #<Class:0x007f89f3
```

I have an enum defined in model as under:

```
class BookEntryAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:pending, :"in-progress", :completed, :approved]
  after_initialize :set_default_status, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_status
    self.status ||= :pending
  end
end
```

I get the error when I try to create a select list:

```
f.select(:status, BookEntryAssignment.status.keys.map {|status| [status.titleize,status] if(!status.eql'approved')}, {:class => 'form-control'})
```

I dont know why this is happening. It might be a very silly mistake from me but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `BookEntryAssignment.statuses` per the docs at http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: @sushant great- please make the answer as the accepted one so people in the future can know this is how you do it

Comment: Hi @SKram, apologies for forgetting.